# Filter only documents that have ALL FIELDS non null (with aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have many documents, but I want to figure out how to get only documents that have ALL FIELDS non null.
Suppose I have these documents:

```
[
 {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
 },
 {
  'a': 9,
  'b': 12
 },
 {
  'a': 5
 }
]
```

So filtering the documents, only the first have ALL FIELDS not null. So filtering out these documents, I would get only the first. How can I do this?

Comment: when you say *ALL FIELDS*, do you know all the names of the fields like `a`, `b`, `c` & how many those could be ?

Comment: No. It can be a lot of fields and I can't write then one by one.

Comment: then I don't think you can do that in a better way, but how many do you think you might have ? Also since you're checking for couple of fields can I say all of your docs should contain only those field names none apart from those ? If that's the case then we can try..

Comment: Yes, the number of unique fields are limited. They are not random.

Comment: Are there arrays with objects as elements? Are there nested arrays or nested sub-documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you wanted to get only the documents which have *ALL FIELDS*, without specifying all of them in filter query like this : `{ a: {$exists : true}, b : {$exists : true}, c : {$exists : true}}` then it might not be a good idea, in other way technically if you've 10s of fields in the document then it wouldn't either be a good idea to mention all of them in the query. Anyhow as you don't want to list them all - We can try this hack if it performs well, Let's say if you've a **fixed schema** & say that all of your documents may contain only fields `a`, `b` & `c` (`_id` is default & exceptional) but nothing apart from those try this :

If you can get count of total fields, We can check for field count which says all fields do exists, Something like below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** add a new field which counts no.of fields in the document */
  {
    $addFields: { count: { $size: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } }
  },
  {
    $match: { count: { $eq: 4 } } // we've 4 as 3 fields + _id
  },
  {
    $project: { count: 0 }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bsMpsU5gY3D)

**Note :** We're only checking for field existence but not checking for false values like `null` or `[]` or `''` on fields. Also this might not work for nested fields.

Just in case if you wanted to check all fields exist in the document with their names, So if you can pass all fields names as input, then try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** create a field with all keys/field names in the document */
    {
      $addFields: {
        data: {
          $let: {
            vars: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } },
            in: "$$data.k"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: { data: { $all: [ "b", "c", "a" ] } } /** List down all the field names from schema */
    },
    {
      $project: { data: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ax2-CgdL1Wg)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

You can try to use [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain) to check your queries performance.

Comment: Nice ideia. Thanks!